# How to create a Dictionary with for value type that is known?

Tags: vb.net, reflection, .net-4.0, dictionary

I want to create a Dictionary where the Key type is Integer and the Value type is the type of the class I am currently executing in.

I've tried the following:

```
Dim col as new Dictionary(Of Integer, Me.GetType())
```

but I am getting an error stating that `keyword does not name a type.

How do I create a dictionary based on the type of the executing class?

Comment: [MakeGenericType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx) ?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov How do I then add items to the Dictionary?  It never actually constructs a dictionary, just a type.

Comment: You get type, than call constructor, than add items (unfortunately I have no idea how to express it in VB.Net , I can give C# sample)... But I hope someone can suggest more reasonable solution. In C# one would also have problem with expressing the resulting type in code (I think `IDictionary` may be the only option) - not sure about VB.Net.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov An example in C# would be good.

Comment: You could use `Object` too, then you can store the type you want

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d3e4b1/dynamically-creating-generic-listt-and-generic-dictionary/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C# sample of creating dictionary of `int` to a type.

Methods used:

- [Type.MakeGenericType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx)
- [Type.GetConstructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h93ya84h.aspx)
- [ConstructorInfo.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ycw1y17.aspx)

The problem is mainly to express resulting type in somewhat type-safe manner. In `Dictionary` case one may resort to `IDictionary`, or continue to use reflection to manipulate objects.

It may also be possible to somehow express most manipulation with generic code which is invoked by more reflection with `MakeGenericMethod`

Sample:

```cs
   var myType = typeof(Guid); // some type

   // get type of future dictionary
   Type generic = typeof(Dictionary<,>);
   Type[] typeArgs = { typeof(int), myType };
   var concrete = generic.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);

   // get and call constructor
   var constructor = concrete.GetConstructor(new Type[0]);
   var dictionary = (IDictionary)constructor.Invoke(new object[0]);

   // use non-generic version of interface to add items
   dictionary.Add(5, new Guid());
   Console.Write(dictionary[5]);

   // trying to add item of wrong type will obviously fail
   // dictionary.Add(6, "test");
```

Comment: What is this line?  `var constructor = concrete.GetConstructor(new Type[0]);`  What Type[0]???

Comment: @AngryHacker `GetConstructor` requires array `Type` object specifying types of each argument of the constructor (to find a match). `new Type[0]` is array of 0 elements - I'm looking for constructor with 0 parameters. You may need to adjust that if you need the other constructors.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the class name `Dim col as new Dictionary(Of Integer, MyClass)`

On a side not using integer as your key can get confusing since a dictionary also uses integer for the index.  If the keys are to be consecutive integers, you might be better served by a list.